# C# DataGridView Highlight Row

Tags: c#, datagridview

DataGridView.. my focus on first column. On the **GRID LOAD** highlight rows with same values.
   Let's say rows with 1's highlight with red, rows with 3's highlight with blue, 5's with        green..
   or 1's with red, no highlight for 3's, 5's with red again (like alternative color).

Idea is to visually separate rows with the same values.

Any ideas guys? Thanks in advance.

```
Column1 | 
------
1 
1     
3
3
3      
5 
5
```

Tried , but can't figure visual separation:

```
int i, i_temp = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgv.Rows)
        {
            i = int.Parse(dr.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString());
            if (i_temp == int.Parse(dr.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString()))
            {
                dr.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                i_temp = i;
            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The prescribed way to do this is in the CellFormatting event.

```
private void MyGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    var dr = MyGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    var intVal = int.Parse(dr.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString());
    switch (intVal)
    {
        case 1:
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            break;
        case 3:
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            break;
        case 5:
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Note that you can apply this to certain columns only by making the formatting conditional on the e.ColumnIndex property.